# How can i compare a int value to multiple string values. so it works on a database. Failed to transform value

Tags: java, date, groovy, date-comparison

Currently I am using an `if` statement in a Groovy function to see compare it and it dosen't work.

```
if ((StartDate<=${Day}) && (${Day}<=EndDate))
   return 1
else
  return 0
```

So guys or girls can u help me out and type a code how to do it using Java? Or fix this code, because I am out of ideas.

I am getting the error:

> Failed to transform value 10-08-2018 of column StartDate in function
>   Func2: Failed to convert value 10-08-2018 in column StartDate to type
>   class java.lang.Short

Comment: the chances of a Date being decently represented by an int is practically nill. either way, you can always parse your Strings to ints and compare them that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to compare date elements.
You can split a complete date instance into month,day and year like this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonthValue();
int year = date.getYear();
```

Hope this will help to get the condition right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using the java.util.date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");
    try {

        Date dStart = sdf.parse("01.01.2001");
        Date dEnd = sdf.parse("01.01.2002");
        Date dCurrent = sdf.parse("01.06.2001");
        if(dStart.before(dCurrent) && dEnd.after(dCurrent)) {
            //return true / 1 here
        }
        else {
            //return false / 0 here
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. : agree with your opinion but everyone is not moved yet on Java 8, people are still using Java 7 and below.

Comment: Oracle support for Java 7 ended after April 2015, so upgrading may be the better option. You may also use java.time with Java 7, though it requires an external library, [ThreeTen backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).